# How to show progress bar from python tqdm to r shiny app

Tags: python, r, shiny, progress-bar, tqdm

I am trying to integrate my python function with R Shiny. The Shiny UI has a button that displays a data frame created by python function upon clicking. The python function has a loop to generate the data frame. I need to show the progress at each step/ iteration of the loop in shiny UI. I have used tqdm to show the progress in python. When i import this python function to R, I can see the progress bar in R console but I am not able to display this progress bar on R shiny.
Below is the python code.

```
    from tqdm import tqdm
    import pandas as pd
    def output_from_visit():
         results = []
         for visit in tqdm(range(0,10)):
             square = visit**2
             output = {}
             output['visit'] = visit  
             output['square'] = square
             results.append(output)
         return results

    def gen():
        a = output_from_visit()
        result_df = pd.DataFrame(a)
        return result_df
```

Below is the R Shiny Code

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate)
library(shinyjs)
reticulate::source_python("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\rshiny\\visit.py")
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("button1", "Click Here")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    tableOutput("result")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$result<-renderTable({
    if (input$button1){
      res = gen()
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also attaching the SS below.[image]

The Data frame that is rendered can be seen in the shiny app and the progress is printed on the R console.
Also would like to know if there is any way by which the python function can return the visit number from the loop into R so that i can make use of progress bar of R shiny instead of tqdm progress bar.